# How to use css vertically centered title?

Tags: html, css

How to use css vertically centered title?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <title>test page</title>

</head>

<body>
  <div style="padding: 8px 8px 10px;border-bottom: 1px solid #e8e8e8;">

    <a href="#" style="overflow-x: hidden;text-overflow: ellipsis;white-space: nowrap;width: 154px;display: inline-block;">
      <img src="http://i.ytimg.com/p/PL-o37YO_uwcLPmR8QBTegC2BoJ03I3tqe/mqdefault.jpg" style="display: inline-block;width: 30px;height: 30px;border: 1px solid #ddd;border-radius: 50%;overflow: hidden;/* vertical-align: -9px; */"> title title title title
      title title title title title title title title title title title title title </a>

    <span style="ctitle;vertical-align: 10px">posttime:2017-11-11 11:21</span> </div>



</body>

</html>
```

[image]

Comment: What exactly is `ctitle;` in `style="ctitle;vertical-align: 10px"` supposed to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add Img tag CSS

```
vertical-align: middle;
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <title>test page</title>

</head>

<body>
  <div style="padding: 8px 8px 10px;border-bottom: 1px solid #e8e8e8;">

    <a href="#" style="overflow-x: hidden;text-overflow: ellipsis;white-space: nowrap;width: 154px;display: inline-block;">
      <img src="http://i.ytimg.com/p/PL-o37YO_uwcLPmR8QBTegC2BoJ03I3tqe/mqdefault.jpg" style="display: inline-block;width: 30px;height: 30px;border: 1px solid #ddd;border-radius: 50%;overflow: hidden;vertical-align: middle;"> title title title title
      title title title title title title title title title title title title title </a>

    <span style="ctitle;vertical-align: 10px">posttime:2017-11-11 11:21</span> </div>



</body>

</html>
```